# JS Script take time to change background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, background, navbar

I have a navbar on bootsrap and i want to change color when the scroll pass the brand name. It's work but it's not immediately, and sometime when I go to top very fast, the background color not change. Or for responsive it's the same, if i put the windows smaller it's take time.

My HTML:

```
<nav class="transparent navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                <img src="img/logo_menu.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-menu">      
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

My CSS:

```
.transparent {
    background:transparent;
}
```

And for finish my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {   
        var scroll_start = 0;
        var startchange = $('.brand-name');
        var offset = startchange.offset();
        $(document).scroll(function() { 
          scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
          if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
              $('.navbar').animate({backgroundColor: "#222222"}, {duration:(500)});
           } else {
              $('.navbar').animate({backgroundColor: "transparent"}, {duration:(500)});
           }
        });
    }
    else {$('.navbar').css('background-color', '#222222');}
});
```

So how can i speed up the all process ?

Comment: @Popnoodles yes its for the smooth stuff (0.5sec). I talk about the time takes to detect

Comment: @Popnoodles look the question, i have edit the html script

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/38ztjw32/ not getting anything at all from the given code

Comment: @Popnoodles I use Bootstrap, im trying to put it on jsfiddle

Comment: Added bootstrap http://jsfiddle.net/38ztjw32/2/

Comment: @Popnoodles http://flavien317builds.herobo.com/lucious/ you can see the result here. The things, its the detection, its take time for have the transparent color or black. Sometime take up to 5sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're queuing animations. `.stop()` them each time.

```
$('.navbar').stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#222222"}, {duration:(500)});
```

and

```
$('.navbar').stop().animate({backgroundColor: "transparent"}, {duration:(500)});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work better, but the first time we go on website, the bar is black, and for responsive, it's little buggy too. How can we fix it ?

Comment: Other questions not covered in this one need asking as other questions. To trigger it without scroll (on page load) you append `.trigger('scroll')`